# Airflow unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, airflow

I would like to be able to unit test my airflow operators without having to run airflow db init before the tests.
Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: here is some link you can visit: [Testing and debugging Apache Airflow](https://godatadriven.com/blog/testing-and-debugging-apache-airflow/) , [How to develop data pipeline in Airflow through TDD (test-driven development)](https://blog.magrathealabs.com/how-to-develop-data-pipeline-in-airflow-through-tdd-test-driven-development-c3333439f358), [Testing in Airflow Part 1](https://medium.com/@chandukavar/testing-in-airflow-part-1-dag-validation-tests-dag-definition-tests-and-unit-tests-2aa94970570c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow is already testing majority of operators without having to `init db`. We are heavily use mocking:

- [Google AutomML ops](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/15baf737eede47e4fe9f8c0850a67d78884f4583/tests/providers/google/cloud/operators/test_automl.py#L92-L118)
- [Google Dataproc ops](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/15baf737eede47e4fe9f8c0850a67d78884f4583/tests/providers/google/cloud/operators/test_dataproc.py#L392-L438)
- [Exasol ops](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/15baf737eede47e4fe9f8c0850a67d78884f4583/tests/providers/exasol/operators/test_exasol.py#L25-L42)

It common to split hook and operator testing. So, first you test hook methods (example [DataprocHook method test](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/15baf737eede47e4fe9f8c0850a67d78884f4583/tests/providers/google/cloud/hooks/test_dataproc.py#L248-L260)) then you test the operators using the hook by mocking it ([corresponding Dataproc example](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/15baf737eede47e4fe9f8c0850a67d78884f4583/tests/providers/google/cloud/operators/test_dataproc.py#L1038-L1070)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the point. However in airflow documentation on best practices (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html), they show an example with an operator ran via a task instance.
I guess that in this task instance case, we have no choice but to run init db right ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: You need to decided what you want to test. If you need only unit tests then no database is needed, just simply test python class and its methods. If you want to run E2E tests then you need Airflow up and running. In Airflow we have both unit and [integration (aka system) tests](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/tests/providers/google/cloud/operators/test_dataproc_system.py) which simply run an example DAG. However, the later ones require not only Airflow but external resources too. Personally I'm happy with unit tests running on CI and example DAG that can be run manually if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer but a different approach on this.

We have the same issue and still experimenting on this. For now we have decided to split the functionality of the custom airflow operator in two parts. Operator itself handling anything that has to do with the db and orchestrates the process and in another module we have the logic of the operator - that has nothing to do with the database.

For example, assume that you have an operator that gets a csv file from a bucket performs transformations and then inserts the file in the database. Lets call it CsvToDBOperator. For this we would have two files/classes.

- CsvToDBOperator
- CsvToDBUtils

The second one will keep all the methods/functions that are responsible for the transformations. The first one will be responsible to get the file from the bucket, pass it to the second for the transformation and then getting the result from it and finally inserting it in the DB.

Like this you can write unit tests for CsvToDBUtils class and only create unit tests on those.